# How to CheckOut, Update and CheckIn a new version of an existing Sharepoint Document in C#

Tags: development, csom, check-out

I'm using C# CSOM to add documents to a Sharepoint library. I'm using the code below which works. How do I modify this code so that if the Document already exists in Sharepoint it will CheckOut the Document, Update it and CheckIn the new version of the Document? Or am I misunderstanding how this works? Thanks.

```
        using (ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(siteUrl))
        {
            using (System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(sourceFilePath, System.IO.FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                FileCreationInformation fcInfo = new FileCreationInformation();
                fcInfo.ContentStream = fs;
                fcInfo.Url = file_name_only;
                fcInfo.Overwrite = true;

                Folder targetFolder = ctx.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(libraryName + "/" + folderPath);
                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File myFile = targetFolder.Files.Add(fcInfo);

                myFile.CheckIn("Initial CheckIn", CheckinType.MajorCheckIn);

                ctx.Load(myFile);
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();
            } 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that it was much easier than I thought. The only complexity was correctly constructing the relativeURL. Oddly, for Get**Folder**ByServerRelativeUrl it was sufficient to have the relative URL as the Library name onwards, but for Get**File**ByServerRelativeUrl I seemed to need the full path including the domain name (i.e. a full path rather than a relative path).

```
        using (ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(siteUrl))
        {
            string relativeURL = SharepointSite + libraryName + "/" + folderPath + "/" + file_name_only;
            bool alreadyInSharePoint = false; ;

            try
            {
                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file = ctx.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(relativeURL);
                file.CheckOut();
                ctx.Load(file);
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                alreadyInSharePoint = true;
            }
            catch (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException ex)
            {
                switch (ex.ServerErrorTypeName)
                {
                    case "System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException":
                    case "System.IO.FileNotFoundException":
                        break;
                    default:
                        throw ex;
                }
            }

            using (System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(sourceFilePath, System.IO.FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                FileCreationInformation fcInfo = new FileCreationInformation();

                fcInfo.ContentStream = fs;
                fcInfo.Url = file_name_only;
                fcInfo.Overwrite = true;

                Folder targetFolder = ctx.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(libraryName + "/" + folderPath);
                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File myFile = targetFolder.Files.Add(fcInfo);


                myFile.CheckIn("Initial CheckIn", CheckinType.MajorCheckIn);

                ctx.Load(myFile);
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();
            }
        }
    }
```